# Is it grammatical to use "hugged" in the following way?

Tags: word-usage

> She chewed the corner of her hugged pillow.

In this sentence *hugged pillow* means the same as *the pillow she was hugging*.

Is using hugged in this way grammatical or commonplace?

Comment: It is grammatical.  However, it sounds very strange to this US English speaker, and I just wouldn't use it.  "The pillow she was hugging" sounds much more fluent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that the past participle of "hug" (hugged) is used in your example sentence seems to be incorrect. It is not commonplace to hear the past participle or past tense of the word directly before the noun.

A better way to put it would be:

> She chewed on the corner of the pillow she was hugging.